# Iterate Similar Records using foreach

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to display records and its related records through the use of @foreach() but each time I keep on getting the error "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type..".
The VS Solution is based on Code First Model and this operation is only on a single class.
Any help and guidance on the same would be helpful:

The Model:

```
public class SingleView //USSD
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string InsurerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RenewalDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller

```
    public ActionResult Details(Int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SingleView singleView = db.SingleViews.Find(id);
        if (singleView == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(singleView);
    }
```

The View:

```
    @model  MinetSingleView.Models.SingleView
    @{

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Client)</td>
                            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InsurerName)</td>
                            <td>Product Type</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PolicyType)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RenewalDate)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PolicyNo)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephone)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
           }
```

The Details section uses an Autoincrement "ID" as the id parameter
e.g. localhost:65129/Home/Details/16

Comment: _"and its related records"_ - but there is nothing in your code that indicates "related records", you query for a single record (`.Find()`) and return one to the view, not multiple.

Comment: so basically the Find() is used to return single records?. What can I use to return multiple ones

Comment: You use `.Where(r => r.SomeCondition)`.

Comment: If @model  List<MinetSingleView.Models.SingleView> then only required iteration

Answer (score 1):

Your model is a *single* object and controller's signature suggest it should return data for only one object - it takes a single id `Details(Int id)`.

You don't need the `foreach`.

Consider the following snippet.

```
var c = new SomeClass();

foreach( var item in c ) 
{
   What to iterate through here? 
}
```

---

A method that returns multiple object would look something like the following.

```
public ActionResult Details(sring clientName )
{
    if (string.IsNUllOrEmpty(clientName))
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var svs = db.SingleViews.Where( sv => sv.Client == clientName).ToList();
    if (!svs.Any())
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(svs);
}
```

The `Model` for this view would be a collection and then you can use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

**The controller**

```
  public ActionResult Details(Int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        List<SingleView> singleView = db.SingleViews.count > 0 ?
                                 db.SingleViews.where(a => a.id == id).tolist() : null ;
        if (singleView == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(singleView);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @model  List<MinetSingleView.Models.SingleView>
    @{

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Client)</td>
                            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.InsurerName)</td>
                            <td>Product Type</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PolicyType)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RenewalDate)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PolicyNo)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephone)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
           }
```

Comment: This would, after it compiles ;), still require changing the model to a collection.

Comment: @model Ienunerable<MinetSingleView.Models.SingleView> try it

Comment: Why dont you `&& singleView.Count > 0`?

Answer (score 0):

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type.."

This error appears because foreach statement can only work on a collection.
Your SingleView is not a collection. You can make it iterable by implementing `GetEnumerator`

Anyways, the easiest way for you would be to make convert it into a list.

And pass the list to the view

just follow **tymtams** example.

And add this line in your view

```
 @model  List<MinetSingleView.Models.SingleView>
```